# How to remove badge from specific tab bar after clicking away from it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, tabbar, badge

I want to remove the badge from the tab bar only after the user clicks away from the tab bar with the badge

For example, the badge appears on the 'News' tab as shown below.

[image]

If I click on the News tab, the badge will still be showing. The badge will only disappear after I click on any other tabs (other than news).

How can I implement this in the app delegate?

EDIT

I tried to set the UITabbardelegate via the following code:

```
tabController.tabBar.delegate = self;
```

But I keep getting the following error

Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

How do I resolve this?

Comment: you should accept an answer already.

Answer (score 10):

In your case, the **1** badge is located on the `index 3` tab, so you would do:

```
[[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setBadgeValue:nil];
```

It's up to you to figure out when the user taps on the tab with the badge,  you can get that feedback by first assigning a `tag` to your tabbar items, then use:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{ 
    switch (item.tag) 
    {
        case 3: /* News */
            /* Tabbar item #3 was pressed, do something here. */
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I check how I can set up the delegate for this so that this metod will be called? I put 'UITabbarDelegate' in the header file and set self.tabbarcontroller.tabbar.delegate = self in the implementation file but did not work. Any advise?

Comment: is the controller a `UITabBarController`? If so, then there is no need to set protocols or delegate.